# Expressing elements of sigma algebra explicitely

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to find a way on how to express elements of a sigma algebra generated by a pi system $\pi$.
Is the following correct? I can't seem to find any general results.

$A\in\sigma( \pi)$ can be written as either $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ or
$\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)^c$ Where either $A_n$ or $A_n^c$ lies in $\pi$.

Thank you.